# wxPython StyledTextCtrl line numbers not starting at 1

Tags: wxpython, wxwidgets, line-numbers, wxstyledtextctrl

I know how to add line numbers to a wxPython StyledTextCtrl, thanks to the wxPython Demos.

```
myctrl.SetMarginType(0, wx.stc.STC_MARGIN_NUMBER)
```

Is there a way to make the line numbering start at something other than 1?

The motivation for this is to show snippets of a large text file.  I want the line numbers to match those in the complete file, but I don't want to load the entire file in my text control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this could be achieved by folding the content you don't wish to display.
More information can be located here: http://www.yellowbrain.com/stc/folding.html

Comment: This is a reasonable workaround.  I just add the needed number of blank lines before my snippet and then hide those blank lines.

Answer (score 1):

I'd hide the default line number margin and use a custom one, see [margins documentation](http://www.scintilla.org/ScintillaDoc.html#Margins) for the details.